# Send args to Firefox when launching from terminal

Tags: terminal, macos, firefox

Additional arguments on start of Google Chrome from Terminal app are send in a following way:

```
open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app   --args -myArgs="ARGS"
```

What is the syntax to sending arguments to Firefox?

Tried the obvious:

```
open /Applications/Firefox.app   --args -myArgs="ARGS"
```

This runs the Firefox, but the args are not set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to pass *arguments* to an application opened by the `open` command, use **both** the `-a` **and** the `--args` *options*.

Example: `open -a Firefox --args -private-window`

From the [`open` man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html): `open [ −a application] file ... [ −−args arg1 ...]`